# Resource not found exception on imageclick

Tags: android, exception, resources, imageview

I am trying to inflate a custom dialog on image click but the program shows following exception.

on image click the following code gets into act

```
iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final Dialog d = new Dialog(About.this);
                d.setContentView(R.layout.abtdial);
                d.setTitle("About developer");
                Button dbt = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                dbt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                d.show();
            }
        });
```

The xml for the custom dialog is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:text="about"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#00BFFF"
            android:textSize="50dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="some text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#848484" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="text abc"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#A9E2F3" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:background="@style/btn"
            android:text="Dismiss"
            android:textColor="#00BFFF"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The stack trace for the following code is

```
 08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class <unknown>
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:421)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at bitcream.my.notepad.About$1.onClick(About.java:32)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 20 more
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060001 a=-1 r=0x7f060001}
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:344)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
    08-17 21:18:42.651: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 23 more
```

Comment: post layout file that you have used on `PhoneLayoutInflater` line 56

Comment: can you please post your activity and xml code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `button1` xml representation you have `android:background="@style/btn"`. `background` attribute accepts drawables, not styles. That's why you have this exception message

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable

Ref: [android:background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background)

Answer (score 0):

If you have in `btn.xml` selector with `button_pressed`, `focused` and `selected` 
something like :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" /> </selector>
```

you need add it to drawable folder

```
android:background="@drawable/btn"
```